# Make multiple delays in chained transitions in D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, nvd3.js, mongoid3

I am moving a rectangle from point a to point i in a picture, i want to mark a stop delay of 5s for each point (there are 8 points). the transitions work fine in the code below (the delay works only for point b).The problem is that i can't add more delays for my other transitions.

Is there any way to do it ?

Thank you all in advance.

```
function TRANSITION(access,dur=10000,Delay=5000,b=390.5,c=523,d=632.5,e=810.8,f=942.5,g=1063,h=1196,i=1334.5)
            {
                access.transition().duration(dur).attr('x',b)
                .transition().delay(Delay).duration(dur).attr('x',c)
                .transition().duration(dur).attr('x',d)
                .transition().duration(dur).attr('x',e)
                .transition().duration(dur).attr('x',f)
                .transition().duration(dur).attr('x',g)
                .transition().duration(dur).attr('x',h)
                .transition().duration(dur).attr('x',i)
            }
```

Comment: You want to move one point, wait 5 seconds, move the next point, wait 5 seconds, etc...?  What is access? A selection of the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a transition that changes no attributes but still has a duration:

```
.transition()
.duration(dur)
.attr('x',d)
.transition()    // don't transition anything
.duration(5000)  // but take five seconds doing it
.transition()
.duration(dur)
.attr('x',e)
```

I've only tested this in version 4, so it is possible that this might not work in version 3. Alternatively, you could add the `.attr` line in the delaying transition if you were to leave some attribute the same.